How to open a overfilled whipped cream dispenser that is stuck and can’t open lid
The dispenser will not let me open the lid. The dispenser was filled to the top and a cartridge at it. I then realized what it happened but cannot get the lid off.

Your best bet is to find an instruction manual. We'd need the exact make and model to be able to answer anyway. I suspect it'll be something along the lines of depressurize, then open as normal.

What happens when you attempt to dispense whipped cream from the container? That's the (apparently) obvious way to lower the volume of liquid and the pressure. It may well not whip the cream nicely, but if the pressure is reduced sufficiently you should be able to get the lid off (or may not need to, depending how it works out.) Perhaps you've tried and it didn't work, but if so, please tell us. Or try, and tell us the result of that attempt. Given it's a whipped cream dispenser, you should be able to hold it "the wrong way up" for dispensing whipped cream and just bleed off gas pressure.

The 'release all pressure' instructions won't work if you've clogged the nozzle.  This once happened when my mom decided to use fresh grated nutmeg (following a recipe that probably assumed you just bought a jar of ground nutmeg from the store).
If you slowly unscrew it VERY slowly, you can scrape some of the whipped cream that will ooze out... right until the point where the top suddenly shoots off and it sprays whipped cream everywhere.
So I would suggest wrapping the whole thing in a large towel and trying to slowly work the lid off (letting it release whatever pressure it can) while it's trapped inside the towel.  And you might want to do this outside, and wear eye protection, just in case.
The pressure is going to add friction to unscrewing it, so you might need something to grip it well... if you have large channel-lock (aka slip joint) pliers, those may work, but again... work VERY slowly, so that any pressure that can escape does so before you hit the point of no return

What is the brand of the whipper?
A common brand is iSi.  The FAQ on their website states:

First release the pressure. Place the whipper with the head upwards and hold a towel over the outlet. Activate the lever until the iSi Whipper is no longer under pressure. Now the head can be removed from the bottle. If the head still cannot be removed, please contact iSi Customer Service at (973) 227-2426 x6245.

You first want to try to release the pressure.  Sometimes working the lever helps.
I see some additional suggestions online about placing it the refrigerator or placing the bottom portion in ice water for a while.  If it is an iSi...call the helpline.
